# SQL Server query issues SUM'ing two columns with a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I wrote a script that takes the SUM of 1 column and divides it by the SUM of another column and I am returned with a whole number.  My issue is I need a decimal number returned to the hundredths place.  The source column data type is decimal as well as the target table/extract.

Below is the code I am using as an example.

```
select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, 
       sum(ColA)/sum(nullif(ColB,0)) [TEST SUM]
from [DB1].[Schema1].[Table1] a
```

From what I understand, being that I am taking data from a decimal datatype column to an extract also as datatype decimal, there shouldn't be any rounding unless I specifically code that in correct?

Comment: If the columns are already a `decimal`, why not just `CONVERT` the value of the expression `[TEST SUM]` to a `decimal(p,2)` where `p` is an appropriate precision?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: There *will* be rounding if the result is an irrational number, eg `1/3` which is `0.3333333333....`.

Comment: As long as at least one column is decimal, you should get decimals back. But probably they aren't or the division is exact

Comment: try to multiply it with 1.0 ... it should return decimal

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: You might play around with this to get some useful info about what's going on: `sql_variant_property()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have individual and aggregate in the query so you have to break it up and re-combine it

```
with cteSample as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1.1, 2.2, 3.3)
        , (1.3, NULL, 3.6)
        , (1.4, 2.5, 3.9)
    ) as SampDat(ColA, ColB, ColC)
), cteSums as (
    select sum(ColA) as SumA
        , sum(nullif(ColB,0.0)) as SumB --0.0 to let SQL know the precision
    from cteSample as a 
)
select ColA, ColB, ColC --Adjust the DECIMAL(18,2) for what you display, the ROUND(,2) for where it rounds
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),ROUND(SumA/SumB,2)) as TEST_SUM
from cteSample as a 
    CROSS JOIN cteSums as S --Only 1 row so CROSS JOIN
```

Comment: You should learn about window functions `sum(ColA) over ()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to avoid having to scan the table twice.

To get a `decimal` result, multiply one side by `1.0`.

```sql
select
  ColA,
  ColB,
  ColC,
  ColD, 
  sum(ColA) over () * 1.0 / sum(nullif(ColB,0)) over () AS [TEST SUM]
from Schema1.Table1 t1
```